# How do I get Android Studio to display my Java code correctly?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After opening Android Studio today, I was greeted with this code instead of the Java code I had before:

```
<component name="ProjectCodeStyleConfiguration">
  <state>
    <option name="USE_PER_PROJECT_SETTINGS" value="true" />
  </state>
</component>
```

Here's what the code originally looked like:

```
package game;

import game.person.Education.Education;

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int intelligence;
    private int health;
    private int happiness;
    private int appearance;
    private Education education;

}
```

Upon further investigation, I found that a lot of the other (Java) files on there had turned into similar non-Java code. When I tried to open the original file with notepad, it gave me the original Java code, which (to me) suggests that I might have messed something up with Android Studio. Is there an easy fix for this problem?

Comment: Looks like you opened a project configuration file by mistake

Comment: @tyler There aren't any project configuration files in that directory, so I think Android Studio turned it into a project config file? Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I do not, there is something wrong with your project that is hard to duplicate without more info unfortunately

Comment: I solved it by clearing the cache, thanks for the help